# Special partition of a number $n$

Tags: combinatorics, generating-functions, integer-partitions

Given any integer $n$, how many ways can it be partitioned in which the number $1$ is not allowed? For instance, if $n=6$, then the partitions obeying the aforementioned rule are $6+0$, $4+2$, $3+3$, and $2+2+2$.

I'm trying to find a nice formula for this. I believe (correct me if I'm wrong) the generating function would be $(1+x^2 +x^3 + x^4 + \dots)^{\lfloor \frac{n}{2} \rfloor}$. The $x$ term vanishes because $1$ is forbidden. The $\lfloor \frac{n}{2} \rfloor$ comes from that fact that the longest string $n$ can be partitioned is from a string of $2's$ or a string of $2's$ and one $3$ (verify this).

Are there any better counting methods? Is there an easy way to find these coefficients?

Comment: the number of partitions of an integer is known to be complicated to compute, but if you name it $p_n$, then you want just $p_n-p_{n-1}$

Comment: I see. Can you tell me if my generating function correct?

Comment: the generating function keeps track of the order. In your example, it counts both 4+2 and 2+4

Comment: How could I modify that so that it doesn't keep track of the order? Or is that the complicated computation part?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory)#Generating_function

Comment: The generating function for the number of partitions of $n$ is $\displaystyle\prod_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{1-x^k}$. If $1$'s aren't allowed, the generating function is $\displaystyle\prod_{k=2}^\infty \frac{1}{1-x^k}$. You won't find a closed form.